# When i try to insert new value, the old value i inserted earlier gets updated. This is my code

Tags: python-3.x

when i inserted the first value and next time when i give different value, the old one gets updated with the new one. I am trying to insert mutiple values and store them without getting them updated. How do i do that?

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', passwd='nazaf123', db='nazafdatabase')

cur = conn.cursor()


cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS EMPLOYEE")

sql = """CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
         FIRST_NAME CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
         LAST_NAME CHAR(20),
         AGE INT,
         SEX CHAR(2),
         SALARY FLOAT )"""

cur.execute(sql)

sql = """INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, AGE, SEX, SALARY)
         VALUES ('Nazaf', 'Anwar', 22, 'M', 10000)"""

try:

        cur.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()

except:

        conn.rollback()

cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM employee;""")

print(cur.fetchall())



cur.close()             
conn.close()
```

Comment: Please explain scenario

Comment: i meant to ask. when i inserted the first value and next time when i give different value, the old one gets updated with the new one. I am trying to insert mutiple values and store them without getting them updated. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any code here which does actual updating, unless you can clarify what you are seeing and what you expect to see the following may not help here.

Right now you are deleting a table and recreating it, this will remove all previous data from it.  Your Insert statement will typically never alter previous rows for which none exist so I am going to take a guess based on your question that you may have an `Update Employee Set (New Data)` which would alter the previous record.

To insert new data you will need to perform another `Insert` command. If you are performing an `Update` command it will update all records and not insert a new row. Typically `Update` is followed at the end with a `where (Conditional Statement)` which lets you limit how the records are modified.

I don't have python or SQL database at this hour this should work. I added onto your provided code however I removed the authentication data.

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect({Connection Data here})

cur = conn.cursor()

sql = """INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, AGE, SEX, SALARY) VALUES ('Nazaf', 'Anwar', 22, 'M', 10000)"""

try:
    cur.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
except:
    conn.rollback()
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM employee;""")
#You should see the current data here.

sql = """INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, AGE, SEX, SALARY) VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 44, 'M', 300000)"""

cur.execute(sql)

cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM employee;""")
#You should see both Nazaf and John

sql = """UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET SALARY=30 WHERE FIRST_NAME='John'"""
cur.execute(sql)

cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM employee;""")
#You should see both Nazaf and John, however John's salary will be 30


sql = """UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET FIRST_NAME='BOB'"""
cur.execute(sql)

cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM employee;""")
#You should see the first names changed to bob.



print(cur.fetchall())

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: It works but i meant to ask. when i inserted the first value and next time when i give different value, the old one gets updated with the new one. I am trying to insert mutiple values and store them without getting them updated. How do i do that? Please help.

Comment: If your running the exact code provided try removing the " Execute Drop" and "Create Table"  lines. They are deleting everything each time you run it. You only need to create a table structure once, typically when the application is first setup.


I modified my answer to reflect this.